# I can not get ubuntu to completely down load, any suggestions

Tags: downloads

I am new to the Ubuntu world and want to start learning, I paid the $15 and tried to download the 16.04.1 iso but i cant ever get a full download. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying an HTTP download or BitTorrent?

Comment: wait, you paid $15? Which site did you download it from?

Comment: Ubuntu is free. Download it from [https://www.ubuntu.com/download](https://www.ubuntu.com/download).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is free. I think you missed the "Not now" button located bottom left corner of the Donation page.

[image]

If your internet connection is slow, download it using torrent. Here is the torrent file: http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

Comment: This is the most probable reason for him to pay $15 for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is open sourced and free to download. You cannot pay 15$ for a Ubuntu ISO, but you can get a tee-shirt for that price,  so if you skipped that, it must have been a scam.

All of the varieties and stuff are on https://www.ubuntu.com/download

If your wifi is slow, try using *BitTorrent* or some other service, it scans the chunks after you have downloaded it. ([credits, I dont want to be rude](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34026961#34026961))

And, Welcome to AskUbuntu! \o/

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is free software. Paying any amount of money to download the Ubuntu ISO is optional, but it is never required.

If you are getting an incomplete download due to an intermittent internet connection or because the server for the download mirror that you selected is down, the solution is to copy the link to download the Ubuntu ISO by following the link from the official Ubuntu version release notes webpage to get to the webpage that has the link to download your ISO file. Each Ubuntu flavor and version has its own release notes webpage. The download links are shown as ordinary links without any optional donation messages.

Then download the Ubuntu ISO file from the terminal with the following command:

```
wget -c <link-to-Ubuntu-ISO-file>
```

If you are running Windows 10, you can use wget in the Bash shell of the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Explanation:

```
-c  
--continue        
    Continue getting a partially-downloaded file. This is useful when you want to   
    finish up a download started by a previous instance of wget, or by another  
    program.
```

If the reason for the interrupted download was that the server for the download mirror was down, you can also restart the download from a different mirror and `wget -c` will automatically resume the download from the same place in the ISO file where it was interrupted. Make sure that you change directories to the directory that contains the partially downloaded file before you restart the download, so that wget can locate the file, otherwise wget will restart the download from the beginning.

Comment: OP wants to download Ubuntu ryt? So how can you ask him to use the terminal?

Comment: What I meant is: "What if the OP has a Windows system from which he is trying to download Ubuntu?"

Comment: If the OP has Windows 10 he can use wget in the Bash shell of the Windows Subsystem for Linux.